# justifying modeling strategies

Tags: r, regression, modeling, ordered-logit, ordered-probit

Working in a social science field, I have a number of *DV*s in my paper, in my writing, I plan to justify my modeling (regression) strategies as follows:

1. For those one-item measurements on social issues stances ("The Federal government should allow illegal immigrants to become citizens, provided they meet certain requirements", strongly agree=1, strongly disagree =7), given the ordinal nature of the *DV*, we used ordered logit regression for modeling.
2. We have also explored ordered probit models, but AIC indicates that the ordered logit models are superior.

Does this sound right to reviewers? I am hoping it does because for 2 key *DV*s only the ordered logit models show statistical significance, other models are only marginally significant.

Thanks!

Comment: To what extent, if any, have you adjusted your significance criteria because of the multiple testing being performed?

Comment: @whuber thanks for asking. I have not adjusted my significance criteria -- it's all 0.05. For my ordered probit/logit models, I did have to convert the t-value to p-value though.

Answer (score 4):

First, I would suggest that you don't rely too much on statistical significance. Practical significance is more important. Second, as suggested in the comments, you will need to ensure that, if you decide to report p-values, that you adjust them for multiple testing.